# FASTApi authentication injection

Tags: python, fastapi

My application has an `AuthenticateService` implemented as follows:

```py
from domain.ports.repositories import ISalesmanRepository
from fastapi import HTTPException, status
from fastapi_jwt_auth import AuthJWT
from fastapi_jwt_auth.exceptions import JWTDecodeError
from shared.exceptions import EntityNotFound
from adapters.api.authentication.config import User


class AuthenticateService:
    def __init__(self, user_repo: ISalesmanRepository):
        self._repo = user_repo

    def __call__(self, auth: AuthJWT) -> User:
        credentials_exception = HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Could not validate credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
        try:
            auth.jwt_required()
            user_id = auth.get_jwt_subject()
        except JWTDecodeError:
            raise credentials_exception

        try:
            user = self._repo.get_by_id(user_id)
            return user
        except EntityNotFound:
            raise credentials_exception
```

So the behavior is basically:

- Is jwt is valid, get user from repository and returns
- Raise 401 if jwt is invalid

The problem is that in every controller implemented I have to repeat the process. I tried to implement a decorator that injects the user into the controller in case of success but I couldn't. I'm sure that the best way to implement this is to use fastAPI's `Depends` dependency injector.
Today, a controller looks something like this:

```py
from typing import Optional

from adapters.api.services import authenticate_service, create_sale_service
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from fastapi_jwt_auth import AuthJWT
from pydantic import BaseModel

router = APIRouter()


class Request(BaseModel):
    code: str
    value: float
    date: str
    status: Optional[str] = None


@router.post('/sale')
def create_sale(request: Request, auth: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_service(auth)
    result = create_sale_service.handle(
        {"salesman": user, "sale": request.dict()}
    )
    return result.dict()
```

How can I abstract my authentication so that my controllers look like any of the versions below:

```py
# Option 1: decorator

@router.post('/sale')
@authentication_required
def create_sale(request: Request, user: User): # User is the `__call__` response from `AuthenticateService` class
    result = create_sale_service.handle(
        {"salesman": user, "sale": request.dict()}
    )
    return result.dict()


# Option 2:
@router.post('/sale')
def create_sale(request: Request, user: User = Depends(authenticate_service)): # Something like that, using the depends to inject User to me
    result = create_sale_service.handle(
        {"salesman": user, "sale": request.dict()}
    )
    return result.dict()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I read a little more the `Depends` documentation and realize whats was going wrong with my attempt to inject the user on controller signature.

Right way to implement:

```py
> AuthService class

class AuthenticateService:
    def __init__(self, user_repo: ISalesmanRepository):
        self._repo = user_repo

    def __call__(self, auth: AuthJWT = Depends()) -> User:
    ...

authenticate_service = AuthenticateService(user_repository)
```

```py
> Controller

@router.post('/sale')
def create_sale(request: Request, user: User = Depends(authenticate_service)):
    result = create_sale_service.handle(
        {"salesman": user, "sale": request.dict()}
    )
    return result.dict()
```

Comment: You can also add it to your `router` as a dependency for all routes, that way you won't suddenly make an endpoint unauthenticated because you forgot to add the `user` parameter. You can then have one `APIRouter` for unauthenticated calls and one for authenticated calls if you need some endpoints to be unauthenticated.

Comment: An "AuthenticatedRouter" is a great idea. I will read more about Router in the FastAPI documentation and probably implement it that way. As soon as I do I update my answer here with the router approach.

Comment: We have two APIRouters in our main app.py, which we then add our subrouters (from the different views) to - one for unauthenticated and one for authenticated routes. It works perfectly fine and gives good readability; you can easily see in both the views and the app router setup what the security context for the routes are.